# python and google maps

Tags: python, google-maps

I have a link

```
link = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=9025+tx-+242+Conroe+TX+77385+77385'
```

Is there a way to get coordinates (latitude, longitude)? Or the full url

```
full_link = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/9025+TX-242,+Conroe,+TX+77385/@30.208773,-95.4398773,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x864737753a8e4bfb:0xf56134eb9c932288!8m2!3d30.208773!4d-95.4376886'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Google Maps Geocoding API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding